# Dynamic selection of visible rows after advanced filtering

Tags: vba, excel, filter

I have a code that first trough advanced filtering, filters a table. After this i want to select all rows in the table except the headers and delete this. In my table i have 20 columns of data and it some rows have data in the first 10 columns and empty cells between column 11 and 20 so i cant really use selection.end(xldown, xlright).select etc because som rows have empty cells.

I cant get my head around how to fix this selection. DO u pros have any tips for this?

```
Sub notWanted()

Range("TabellInDataPivot[[#All],[Projekt]]").AdvancedFilter Action:= _
    xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Groupfiles").Range("C8:E9"),   Unique _
    :=False

    lastrow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GruppData").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     .Range(.Cells(4, 3).Offset(rowoffset:=1), .Cells(lastrow, 20)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select

     Selection.EntireRow.Delete
     ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

I get an invalid or unqualifed reference error with the code line .Range**(.Cells**(4, 3) Altough this works fine at earlier filter and delete segments.

Thanks in advance
/D

Answer (score 0):

Excel doesn't seem to allow you to delete rows in a filtered table. In a situation like this, I think you have to only filter with the macro, then select all visible rows and click OK [on the prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbSHJ.png). Happy to hear if anyone has found a VBAish way around this.

Comment: Thanks for the input Josh! I keep on trying but i would also like to hear if someone has a VBAish way around this.

Answer (score 0):

I think i got it!!

My code results are as follow,

```
Sub notWanted()


With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GD")

Range("TabellInDataPivot[[#All],[Projekt]]").AdvancedFilter Action:= _
    xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Groupfiles").Range("C8:E9"), Unique _
    :=False

    lastrow0 = .Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Cells(2, 52).Select
.Range(Cells(3, 1), Cells(lastrow0, 55)).Rows.EntireRow.Select
Selection.EntireRow.Delete
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End With
End Sub
```

I added a lastrow statement and thereafter entirerow.delete. It seems to work so i hope it will do its thing!